# How to login android app with Cakephp's Database?

Tags: android, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I have "online support" module on my Cakephp site, I want to create an android app for administrator of my site to give customers answers. Which method is more secure?

> 1 - create webservice in cakephp
>   
>   2 - i plan to directly connect Mysql
>   
>   3 - HTTP authentication

Answer (score 0):

You should create a web service.

You can also identify device from `$this->request`.